# Machine Learning Algorithm selection

Tags: machine-learning

I am new in machine learning. My problem is to make a machine to select a university for the student according to his location and area of interest. i.e it should select the university in  the same city as in the address of the student. I am confused in selection of the algorithm can I use Perceptron algorithm for this task.

Answer (score 1):

There are no hard rules as to which machine learning algorithm is the best for which task. Your best bet is to try several and see which one achieves the best results. You can use the [Weka toolkit](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/), which implements a lot of different machine learning algorithms. And yes, you can use the perceptron algorithm for your problem -- but that is not to say that you would achieve good results with it.

From your description it sounds like the problem you're trying to solve doesn't really require machine learning. If all you want to do is match a student with the closest university that offers a course in the student's area of interest, you can do this without any learning.

Answer (score 1):

I second the first remark that you probably don't need machine learning if the student has to live in the same area as the university.  If you want to use an ML algorithm, maybe it would best to think about what data you would have to start with.  The thing that comes to mind is a vector for a university that has certain subjects/areas for each feature. Then compute a distance from a vector which is like an  ideal feature vector for the student.  Minimize this distance.

Answer (score 1):

The first and formost thing you need is a labeled dataset.

It sounds like the problem could be decomposed into a ML problem however you first need a set of positive and negative examples to train from.

How big is your dataset? What features do you have available? Once you answer these questions you can select an algorithm that bests fits the features of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using decision trees for this problem which resembles a set of if else rules. You can just take the location and area of interest of the student as conditions of if and else if statements and then suggest a university for him. Since its a direct mapping of inputs to outputs, rule based solution would work and there is no learning required here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a "recommender system"or a clustering  approach , you can investigate more deeply the  techniques like "collaborative filtering"(recommender system) or k-means(clustering) but again, as some people said, first you need data to learn from, and maybe your problem can be solved without ML.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no straightforward and sure-shot answer to this question. The answer depends on many factors like the problem statement and the kind of output you want, type and size of the data, the available computational time, number of features, and observations in the data, to name a few.

1. Size of the training data
2. Accuracy and/or Interpretability of the output

Accuracy of a model means that the function predicts a response value for a given observation, which is close to the true response value for that observation. A highly interpretable algorithm (restrictive models like Linear Regression) means that one can easily understand how any individual predictor is associated with the response while the flexible models give higher accuracy at the cost of low interpretability.

3. Speed or Training time

Higher accuracy typically means higher training time. Also, algorithms require more time to train on large training data. In real-world applications, the choice of algorithm is driven by these two factors predominantly.

Algorithms like Naïve Bayes and Linear and Logistic regression are easy to implement and quick to run. Algorithms like SVM, which involve tuning of parameters, Neural networks with high convergence time, and random forests, need a lot of time to train the data.

4. Linearity

Many algorithms work on the assumption that classes can be separated by a straight line (or its higher-dimensional analog). Examples include logistic regression and support vector machines. Linear regression algorithms assume that data trends follow a straight line. If the data is linear, then these algorithms perform quite good.

5. Number of features

The dataset may have a large number of features that may not all be relevant and significant. For a certain type of data, such as genetics or textual, the number of features can be very large compared to the number of data points.